# A screen with transparent content - JVM bug or not?

Tags: 14.04, java

I am not sure if this is Android Studio bug or something bad with my Java library. This also happens sometimes in Thunderbird and Firefox. I think in a few other Java apps, thou I cannot recall its names now.

I managed to catch the bug in Android Studio app.

When I want to load app to the device or emulator, a "Choose Device" screen appears without any content. Everything is transparent but the parent screen.

[image]

[image]

As you can see, the screen is totally transparent.

This happens so randomly that I was unable to find any pattern when it will happen.

I am on Ubuntu 14.04 x64 machine running the latest Android Studio. This happened even a year back, but I was unable to take snapshots until now.

Comment: This bug is still active. No one has it but me? I event switched to official Java JDK, but it's still present.

Comment: I have it also. Tried different JDK with Android Studio, and still can't find why it's happening.